# Trouble applying function to data frame

Tags: r

Toy example:

```
> myfn = function(a,x){sum(a*x)}
> myfn(a=2, x=c(1,2,3))
[1] 12
```

Good so far. Now:

```
> df = data.frame(a=c(4,5))
> df$ans = myfn(a=df$a, x=c(1,2,3))
Warning message:
In a * x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

> df
  a ans
1 4  26
2 5  26
```

What I want to happen is that for the first row, it is as if I called `myfn(a=4, x=c(1,2,3)`, giving an answer of `24`, and for the second row, it is as if I called `myfn(a=5, x=c(1,2,3)` giving an answer of 30. How do I do this? Thank you.

EDIT: slightly more complex version. Now suppose that the function is

```
myfn = function(a,b, x){sum((a+b)*x)}
```

and that I have the data frame

```
df = data.frame(a=c(4,5), b=c(6,7), c=c(9,9))
```

I want to create `df$ans` such that, for the first row it is as if I called `myfn(a=4, b=6, x=c(1,2,3)` and for the second for it is as if I called `myfn(a=5, b=7, x=c(1,2,3)`, that is, use `df$x` for `a`, `df$y` for `b`, and ignore `df$z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways this can be done, each with it's own charms. If you don't want to modify the function I would just do

```
mapply(myfn, df$x, df$y, MoreArgs = list(x = 1:3))
```

Alternatively, you can bake the iteration right into the function, e.g,

```
myfn = function(a,b, x){
    sapply(a+b, function(ab) {
        sum(ab*x)
    })
}
myfn(df$x, df$y, 1:3)
```

That's probably the way I would do it.

Comment: Thanks. Supposing that `x` is some arbitrary vector, maybe empirical data, rather than `1:3`, is there any way to use the `mapply` approach?

Comment: Sure, you can specify any values for `x` that you like. If `x` varies along with `a` and `b` just put the values in a list (where `length(a) == length(b) == length(x)`) and pass it in the `...` list along with `a` and `b` instead of putting it in `MoreArgs`.

Comment: OK. Got it. Basically I just need to call `list()` on my existing values before passing them in. Thanks!

Comment: Actually...what if there are two vectors I need to pass in? (in the non-toy situation). Is there a way to use `MoreArgs` with say an `x` and a `y`?

Comment: As the plural `MoreArgs` suggests, you can pass more than one argument. See `?mapply` for details.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
myfn = function(a,x){
  return(sum(a*x))
  }

df <- data.frame(a=c(4,5))
df$ans <- apply(df, 1, myfn, x = c(1,2,3))
df$ans

  a ans
1 4  24
2 5  30
```

** Edited Based On User Edit **

```
df = data.frame(a=c(4,5), b=c(6,7), c=c(9,9))
df$ans <- apply(df[, c("a", "b")], 1, function(y) sum((y['a']+y['b'])*c(1,2,3)))
  a b c ans
1 4 6 9  60
2 5 7 9  72
```

Comment: Thanks. What if `myfn` took in two constants as arguments, in addition to the vector, that were stored as columns in the data frame...would the call then be `apply(df, 1, 2, myfn, x = c(1,2,3))`?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean. Could you update your post to reflect what you want?

Comment: Thanks for this...can this be done without typing out the whole function inside the `apply`? The actual function I want to use is quite long...

Comment: Not sure, I would just type it and use some line breaks. Probably go with the mapply approach if that is what you want

Comment: Yah I did end up going with `mapply`. Thank you for the help!